# When I turn off the ec2 serial console broswer window does process survive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi a quick question using the ec2 serial console...
I've currently migrating an EBS volume to an another EBS volume of different size.

I'm using the ec2 serial console on the browser to do this, and moving the data from the original EBS volume to the new one seems to take quite a while.

I was wondering if somehow I loose connection to the internet or turn off my browser, would it terminate the process that was running on the ec2 serial console?

Or would it be just running in the background and continue showing the background once I regain the connection? I know this is something that I could try out for myself but I really running out of time and can't afford to start migration from the beginning again. Help would be super great! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will terminate the program when you loose connection. To protect against that, usually people use a terminal multiplexes, such as [tmux](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/tmux-tutorial-install-commands).

This way you run your commands in `tmux` and it will continue the execution of you programs due to any disconnections.

Comment: @Aesop, you can use `nohup $yourcopycommand &` but better solution is to use `tmux` or any other similar utility.

Comment: @Marcin Ah... so ec2 serial connect behaves almost same like ssh connection... Thank you all!